# Can't edit redirect URLs in new API console

Tags: google-oauth

I have a long standing app, for which I want to add an additional redirect URL for a new test server.

When I click Edit Settings for my web app, I get a modal box containing my existing redirect URL, but a blank textarea for my existing Javascript origins. If I paste my existing Javascript origins into the textarea, it's colored red and the Update button is disabled.

Just to repeat, this is a long standing app. All I want to do is add one new redirect URL

Comment: What does the red error show? 'Origin URIs must not contain a path?' or something else?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a new redirect URl, you need to add it in the text area "AUTHORIZED REDIRECT URI".

Text area "AUTHORIZED JAVASCRIPT ORIGINS" is not for redirect uri, it contains origins where your app is allowed to access the Google APIs.(Origins cannot contain a wildcard or a path)

[image]

Comment: thanks, I'm aware of the meaning of the two fields. My app requires both, as there is a server component and a JS client component. My problem is that if I paste my existing JS origin values into the field, it shows them as being invalid. I simply want to add an additional redirect URL, without touching the existing JS origin values.

Comment: Can you elaborate where these fields are? I can't find them

Answer (score 0):

Worked around by using the old console URL https://code.google.com/apis/console/b/0/?noredirect

I suspect the issue was some chrome-extension urls I had configured

Comment: this link redirect the new console

Comment: Looks like Google have retired the old console.