# Can't find redirect urls in new Google Developer Console

Tags: authentication, google-api

I have a google app that worked fine until yesterday, but now I get 400 origin_mismatch when users try to authorize.
I'm looking for the redirect uri settingd in the new apps console but it is "gone".
[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26326079/cant-edit-redirect-urls-in-new-api-console) looks good but he doesnt specify where are those fields.

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: try visiting here it may help:https://console.developers.google.com/project/adept-bond-576/apiui/apis/library?authuser=0

Comment: It says "You do not have sufficient permissions to view this page.". strange, I am the creator of the app.

Comment: see this thread:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11330919/correct-redirect-uri-for-google-api-and-oauth-2-0

Answer (score 0):

[Solution moved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/309552/997587) from [@EhudGrand](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1223457/ehud-grand)'s question post.

> Found the answer: under APIs & auth -> Credentials, click on your clientid. It would lead you to the relevant screen.